# How to implement infinite scrolling in table data?

Tags: jquery

How to implement infinite scrolling in table data by using php and jquery?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want us to do your work! Please try to find a solution and ask why it's not working and provide your code.

To point you in the right direction:

- check if the user is an the end of the page [Alert using Jquery when Scroll to end of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799542/alert-using-jquery-when-scroll-to-end-of-page)
- do an ajax call to your php script http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- generate the HTML code or an JSON response in your php code
- add the HTML data to the table or generate the the new rows from the JSON response

Answer (score 0):

If you mean scrolling text, you could put some scrolling text into a div and put that into a table cell. See my answer here:

[jQuery: actual div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208562/jquery-actual-div-width/9208773#9208773)